# Graphql : issue constructing query on array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

This is my data stored in MongoDB:

```
{
   "experience":{
      "pastProjects":[
         {
            "1":[
               {
                  "title":"One"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "2":[
               {
                  "title:":"TWO"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is my mongoose schema.

```
const pastProjectsSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    experience: {
        pastProjects:[
            { 
                1: [
                    { 
                        title: String
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
        
})
```

This is my Graphql Query in my typeDefs.

```
export const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
        experiences:[Experience]
    }
    type Experience{
        experience: String
    }

`;
```

I am sure it is not a string I want back just not sure how to structure the gql to match the mongoose.Schema.

Answer (score 0):

]Solved Solution [

I took some time to restructure the JSON.
It looks like this in MongoDB.

```
          {
    "pastprojects": [{
            "title": "One Title",
            "main": "- Blah Line 1<br>- Blah Line 2",
            "sub": "Sub One Description"

        },
        {
            "title": "Two Title",
            "main": "- Blah Line 1<br>- Blah Line 2",
            "sub": "Sub Two Description"

        }

    ]
}
```

This is my mongoose.model in file Book.js:

```
    import mongoose from "mongoose";
const pastProjectsSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
        pastprojects:[
                {   
                    title: String,
                    main: String,
                    sub: String
                }
            ]
            
    })
    
    export const Experience = mongoose.model( "Experience", pastProjectsSchema , "pastprojects");

This is my GraphQl typeDefs.js:

        import gql from 'graphql-tag';   
    export const typeDefs = gql`
        type Query {
            experiences: [Experience]
        }
        type Experience {
            pastprojects: [ProjectDetail]
          }
        
          type ProjectDetail {
            title: String
            main: String
            sub: String
          }
           
    `;
```

This is my resolver.js :

```
    import { Experience} from './models/Book.js'

export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        experiences: async() => await Experience.find({}),
    }
};
```

Thanks Cankat Saraç for helping me with the gql structure.